# Specify DB table in laravel query

Tags: php, laravel

Im new to laravel, i am trying to query a specific table in my DB. I only have 1 data table and the standard user auth tables. I am getting a error: BadMethodCallException
Call to undefined method App\Figures::table().

Model

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Figures extends Model
{
   
}
```

controller

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Figures;

class figuresController extends Controller
    public function figurespag2() {
        $dummyDetails = Figures::table('figures')->where('name', 'batman');
        return view ( 'pagination2.index' )->withUsers($dummyDetails);
       }
```

route

```
Route::get ( '/pagination2', 'figuresController@figurespag2' );
```

I know it's going to be something obvious, but I am new to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is wrong

`$dummyDetails = Figures::table('figures')->where('name', 'batman');`

**Method 1---------- laravel `eloquent`**

**Model**

```php
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Figures extends Model
{
   protected $table = 'figures';
}
```

**Controller**

```php
  $dummyDetails = Figures::where('name', 'batman')->get();
```

---

and
**Method 2 ---------- laravel `Query Builder`**

```php
  $dummyDetails = \DB::table('figures')->where('name', 'batman')->get();
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked. I need to look at models more as I thought the model defines the  DB level interaction which I can see is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

*Use this you not need to define table name*

```
 public function figurespag2() {
        $dummyDetails = Figures::where('name', 'batman')->get();
        return view ( 'pagination2.index' )->withUsers($dummyDetails);
       }
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, it helped me to understand the relationship of the model to the query and controller. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

First you may need to know laravel model rules.

If you create a table name like "**figures**" (plural) you need to create its model by **Figure** (singular).

if you create a table other then this rule then you have to mentioned table name in model like this.
protected $table = "table_name";

you can access table with where condition in controller like this.

```
  public function figurespag2() {
    $dummyDetails = Figure::where('name', 'batman')->get();
    return view ( 'pagination2.index' )->withUsers($dummyDetails);
   }
```

Hope this may help you.

Comment: Thank you for the additional clarification. I am new to Laravel and its getting used to the MVC approach.